# for loop for multiple values of column using python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I got stuck in defining loop over values of a column. 
So, I am applying ARIMA model to time series data. The data includes, one client's order with respective to different countries.So Arima model will apply for different countries for that particular client. For that purpose my challenge is looping that country column and use ARIMA for each country and  here only I am getting stuck. The data is as:

```
Date        ClientName  Country  order
2016-11-05  ABC         Albania       9
2016-11-05  ABC1        Belgium       1
2016-11-05  ABC2        Cambodia      8
2016-11-05  MCN1        Canada        4
2016-11-05  MCN2        China         1
```

In above data I have to model data for each country. 
If anyone help me in this problem it will be great.

Comment: Can you show your desired output, as well as your current code?

Comment: Are you looking to apply your ARIMA model with different parameters for each country? If so, you would probably benefit from a [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) operation. If you provide more information about the model and desired output, we could be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

```
for i, x in df.iterrows():
    print (i)
    print (x)

0
Date          2016-11-05
ClientName           ABC
Country          Albania
order                  9
Name: 0, dtype: object
1
Date          2016-11-05
ClientName          ABC1
Country          Belgium
order                  1
Name: 1, dtype: object
2
Date          2016-11-05
ClientName          ABC2
Country         Cambodia
order                  8
Name: 2, dtype: object
3
Date          2016-11-05
ClientName          MCN1
Country           Canada
order                  4
Name: 3, dtype: object
4
Date          2016-11-05
ClientName          MCN2
Country            China
order                  1
Name: 4, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is use the iterrows and then you can access every column you want

```
for index , row in df.iterrows():
    print row['ClientName'] , row['Country'] , row['order']
```

index will be the index of the row.